# How can I alter the form to add a new validation handler?

Tags: forms, media

I'm on Drupal 8. I have created a new media bundle (*permissions_json*) which can be created from /media/add/permissions_json, where administrator user can upload specifically formatted JSON files, and I can upload to it all fine and dandy.

I'd like to validate the file uploaded and rename it. The problem is that I can't find a way to hook into the form. Implementing `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` with `gp_mcs_media_permissions_json_add_form_alter()` or `gp_mcs_form_media_permissions_json_add_form_alter()` doesn't have any effect. Even the following implementation didn't have any effect.

```php
function gp_mcs_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form);
}
```

If I put a simple `exit()` on the module's page stops the website, so the file is accessible. I just can't figure out how to add validation to this add media form.

How can I alter the form to add a new validation handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form ID for an entity is a string that is usually returned from [`EntityForm::getFormId()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityForm.php/function/EntityForm%3A%3AgetFormId/8.9.x), if the class used for the form doesn't override that method.

This means that, by default, the form ID follows the `<entity>_<bundle>_<operation>_form` schema, where the `<operation>` part is omitted, when *operation* is *default*.
Since [the Media module doesn't have a class that overrides `EntityForm::getFormId()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityForm.php/function/overrides/EntityForm%3A%3AgetFormId/8.9.x), the correct ID for the form that creates a new Media entity whose bundle is *permissions_json* is *media_permissions_json_add*. This means that a module whose machine name is *gp_mcs* can alter that form by implementing `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` with a function named `gp_mcs_form_media_permissions_json_add_alter`. (Note that the form ID is between *form* and *alter*.)